# renaming files script error

Tags: command-line, scripts, batch-rename

I wrote code to change the name of bulk of file it should replace spaces with underscores  and lowercase all the file name ..

this is the code

```
for file in *;
do mv "$file" `echo $file | sed -e 's/  */_/g' -e 's/_-_/-/g'`;
do mv -f "$file" `echo "$file" | tr A-Z a-z`;
done;
```

I know the variable `$file` will change after the 2nd line so it will give error in the 3rd line

I can divide it into 2 loops and then it will work but I need advise how to overcome this in one `for` loop only

Comment: what do you just want to remove all blank spaces and make all capital letters lowercase?

Answer (score 1):

To rename files, it is probably simpler to use perl's `rename` utility (sometimes called `prename`).  I will assume, though, that you are doing this as an exercise in learning shell scripting.

To fix the immediate problem, all you need is a second shell variable, here called `new`:

```
for file in *
do
    new=$(echo "$file" | sed -e 's/  */_/g' -e 's/_-_/-/g')
    mv -f "$file" "$(echo "$new" | tr A-Z a-z)"
done
```

Another approach is to extend the pipeline:

```
for file in *
do
    mv -f "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed -e 's/  */_/g' -e 's/_-_/-/g' | tr A-Z a-z)"
done
```

If you have GNU sed, then the pipeline can be simplified further:

```
for file in *
do
    mv -f "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed -e 's/  */_/g' -e 's/_-_/-/g' -e 's/.*/\L&/')"
done
```

#### Notes

1. Since you used the `-f` option to `mv`, it is possible that this script will cause files in your directory to be overwritten and their contents lost.
2. Consider using `$(...)` in place of backquotes for command substitution.  The dollar-parens form nests well, it is visually clear, and it avoids that confusion that happens because many fonts don't show a clear difference between back ticks and regular ticks.
3. Many languages require a semicolon at the end of each command.  shell is not one of those languages: the newline character ends a command just the way a semicolon does.

Comment: OK thanks , i will go with the second advise to extend the pips